# How to deploy a fullstack MERN project on Vercel?

Tags: reactjs, deployment, vite, vercel

I have recently completed a MERN project and tried to deploy it on Vercel thrice. It doesn't give any error while deploying but shows [![enter image description here][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vATA8.png I first created it in create-react-app but it give the same error on vercel. so i shifted the whole project in Vite..
I have added a vercel.json file in frontend and .Procfile in backend too.
selected Vite in build but non of it works. Can anyone please help?
i have 2 folders, backend and frontend.

Answer (score 0):

You have connect your github to the vercel dashboard?
My vercel build with Vite isn't need a vercel.json file.
[image: build command]

See my build command.
If you have some environment to add, make it in settings.
For back end, try to deploy in Onrender, in vercel I don't got success.